# Why is it buggy to load a sequence of images with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sequence, cycle

I am loading a sequence of images (50 images) with javascript in my website to cycle through, even though it works fine locally, it is really slow/buggy when the site is live. I don't think it is a question of optimizing the images because they're already fairly small in file size. (68kb each, in total they are 1MB). Also it is way faster to load a 4MB gif on my site coming from the same host. Is there something I can change to my code to improve this?

Here's what I currently have: (for the javascript)

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
            var src = 'spacefox_TT/';
            $('#animation').attr('src' , src+counter+'.jpg');
            counter++;
            if(counter > 49 ){
                counter = 1
            }
        }, 50);
    });
```

My html is fairly simple, looks like this:

```
<img id="animation" src="spacefox_TT/1.jpg">
```

And so the script is just incrementing the jpgs until 49 and repeating.

Sorry if this isn't clear, anything helps! Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to chain `img` `src` every `50ms`? `javascript` at Question does not wait for `load` of `img` to complete before setting next `src`.

Comment: Hi! I wasn't trying to chain every 50ms. I am unsure of how to modify the javascript so that it loads img before setting next src...

Comment: What is the duration each image should be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to download these images from server to the user's browser, that's why it will appear as buggy at first. I recommend you using gif instead of trying to change image's src every 50ms. That way the animation won't start before it's loaded. Your method is not buggy, just not efficient in general.

If you really wanna use your method then I recommend you use jQuery's `onload`. You can wrap `setInterval` into some function and execute it only after all images have been loaded.

Comment: I was refraining from using gif because I didn't want to sacrifice the quality of the image. Good to know about onload! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your browser's developers tools and watch the Network tab, you'll see that you're essentially DoS'ing yourself by queuing up thousands of image requests that the browser can't handle as fast as you're adding them.

You have a few options, but one thing to keep in mind is that fewer network requests is generally better for performance, even if you're pulling bigger files.

So what I'd recommend is to chain  your 50 images together into one image that's just really wide (i.e. 50 side-by-side images of the same size).  Your base HTML would look like this:

```
<div class='image-frame'>
  <img src='/image.jpg' alt='Product Image reel' />
</div>
```

Then your base CSS could be something like:

```
.crop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.crop img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
}
```

And you can use JavaScript to apply negative and positive margin to the image to shift between images.  Note that the widths and margins and stuff will need to adjust for the size of the frames you're using, I didn't look that closely at the images you currently have.

Comment: Thank you, this response was helpful!